# CLR IN MOBILE ----is it possible to use virtual machine on mobile os

Tags: c#

as jvm makes java as plateform independent is it possible with CLR to make .net framework supported languages like c# plateform independent on mobile

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Mono CLR. Mono is the open source implementation of C#, .NET BCL and the CLR.

[MonoTouch runs on the iPhone](http://monotouch.net/)

[MonoDroid runs on Android devices](http://monodroid.net/)

Comment: suppose that using mono platform i develop an application using c# for addition of two numbers,after complication of application can it be install on mobile phone for example on nokia-5130, as mono is cross platform i think it should work

Comment: @Neha Mono is cross platform, but there are still unique hardware and operating system requirements for each phone handset that require targeted ports of the Mono CLR and different installation routes. Since the Nokia phone is neither iOS or Android, it wouldn't be possible to use C# on that phone. You can read a platform support summary here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/mono-is-frequently-used-to-say-yes-net-is-cross-platform-how-valid-is-that-c/20436#20436

Answer (score 0):

Yes-ish. At the tooling level, see MonoDroid, MonoTouch or the WP7 tools. However, in each case you are using the language to target a specific mobile platform. You may need different UI code for each, even if the core code is shared.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Compact Framework works on mobile devices (and has for about 8 years now).  .NET is also cross-platform (kind of) through the Mono and MonoTouch projects.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, but each handset has it's own limitations that may not make it very feasible.

If you look at the [mono-project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), it's a portable implementation of the CLR which can target mobile architectures, but it's still an area of development and not very mature yet.

MonoDroid is the project targetting Android handsets, but it's in a beta stage at the moment.

MonoTouch can target iOS, but it cannot take full advantage of the framework. Apple's licensing prevents virtual machines from running on the iOS, so .NET applications need to be AOT (Ahead-of-time) compiled to run on it. This works, but you won't be able to use parts of the BCL like the reflection API.

There's some early development for mono to support WebOS (Palm) too.

Comment: suppose that using mono platform i develop an application using c# for addition of two numbers,after complication of application can it be install on mobile phone for example on nokia-5130, as mono is cross platform i think it should work